# How to read & crawl url & web site file content simultaneously c#

Tags: c#

i am developing a small crawler which will be only used for our company web site. crawler will take a url and crawl that url, read content of that url and also extract others urls in that page and start crawl those url....same way process goes and read file content and as well as crawl other url and read their content too.

i want to do all these task simultaneously. more than 1 yrs back i developed a multi-thread file downloader which downloads files simultaneousely.

here is bit snippet for downloading files simultaneousely.

```
var list = new[] 
{ 
    "http://google.com", 
    "http://yahoo.com", 
    "http://stackoverflow.com" 
}; 

var tasks = Parallel.ForEach(list,
        s =>
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("starting to download {0}", s);
                string result = client.DownloadString((string)s);
                Console.WriteLine("finished downloading {0}", s);
            }
        });
```

it would be very helpful if some one guide me how to code for achiving my goal. thanks

Comment: Your question is very broad for a simple SO answer and your code snippet is not even related to it. Please edit this or it'll likely be closed.

Comment: How many thread can run simultaneously by parallel.foreach ?

Comment: i apologized that i could not explain my problem properly.i want to develop a small crawler in such a way when crawler start parsing any url first time then it will extract all url from content and add those url to a queue and another part in same program will monitor that queue. the moment a new url will be added to queue that a new thread will start to parse that url and extract all url from that content and add to queue. once any url content's parsing will be completed then that url will be removed from the queue. just guide me sample code and idea how to develop this kind of program.

Answer (score 1):

Getting the HTML

```
public string getHTML(string url)
{
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
 HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
 StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
 string html = sr.ReadToEnd();
 sr.Close();
 response.Close();
 return html;
}
```

To parse the code use a parser like: [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net)

Comment: i am not after to read web page content. my problem is that when i will extract url from pages then how to recursively parse content for those pages in same time using Task library? idea would be appreciated.